# Efficient identification of high/low hits in a long vector

Tags: r, performance, for-loop

I have a vector `x` and would like to know for every element `i` in this vector (`x[i]`) whether the subsequent sequence of numbers either hits `x[i] + con` or `x[i] - con` first (where `con` is a constant). Whenever `x[i] + con` is hit first, I'd like to get a 1, a 0 otherwise.

I'd do this with R as shown in the minimal working example below:

```
x   <- cumsum(rnorm(1000000))
con <- 10

hit <- NULL
for (i in 999000:length(x)) {
  hithi  <- min(which(x[i:length(x)] >= x[i] + con))
  hithi  <- ifelse(is.infinite(hithi), 1000000, hithi)
  hitlo  <- min(which(x[i:length(x)] <= x[i] - con))
  hitlo  <- ifelse(is.infinite(hitlo), 1000000, hitlo)
  hit[i] <- ifelse(hithi < hitlo, 1, 0)
  if (i %% 1000 == 0) {
    print(i)
  }
}
```

However, you'll see yourself that this is extremely slow and thus I wonder whether there's a faster way getting the result. How would you do it?

Thanks lot in advance!

Comment: 'Whenever x[i] + con is hit first, I'd like to get a 1, a 0 otherwise.' You don't say what should happen if x[i] - con is hit first. Should it produce a -1? If it's a zero, there's no distinction between cases where there's x[i] - con first or neither making reference to x[i] - con irrelevant.

Comment: With minimal effort you can make gains by converting `min(which(x[i:length(x)] >= x[i] + con))` to `which(x[i:length(x)] >= x[i] + con)[1L]`. Surely there are much much faster solutions by using more advanced algorithms but it takes work to implement them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Idea

In your `for` loop, when you start iterating from index `i`, you actually don't need to fetch all occurrence of high/low hits, but just stop the iteration once the **first hit** (either for high or low) happens at `j` for `j >= i`. Then you refresh your starting point with `i+1` and repeat the process above.

In other words, your origin approach `min(which(...))` is unnecessarily inefficient since it gives all indices info and takes the first one only, while it could be much faster if you terminate the iteration as long as you find the first hit, then enter the next round.

## Code

Maybe you can try the `for` loops like below

```
L <- length(x)
hit <- vector(length = L)
for (i in 1:L) {
   for (j in i:L) {
      d <- x[j] - x[i]
      if (d >= con) {
         hit[i] <- 1
         break
      }
      if (d <= -con) {
         break
      }
   }
}
```

## benchmark

Defining candidates like below

```
f1 <- function() {
   hit <- NULL
   for (i in 1:length(x)) {
      hithi <- min(which(x[i:length(x)] >= x[i] + con))
      hithi <- ifelse(is.infinite(hithi), length(x), hithi)
      hitlo <- min(which(x[i:length(x)] <= x[i] - con))
      hitlo <- ifelse(is.infinite(hitlo), length(x), hitlo)
      hit[i] <- ifelse(hithi < hitlo, 1, 0)
   }
   hit
}

f2 <- function() {
   L <- length(x)
   hit <- vector(length = L)
   for (i in 1:L) {
      xi <- x[i]
      for (j in i:L) {
         d <- x[j] - xi
         if (d >= con) {
            hit[i] <- 1
            break
         }
         if (d <= -con) {
            break
         }
      }
   }
   hit
}
```

we run the following benchmarking test

```
set.seed(0)
x <- cumsum(rnorm(10000))
con <- 5
microbenchmark(
   f1 = f1(),
   f2 = f2(),
   times = 10L,
   unit = "relative",
   check = "equivalent"
)
```

and we see that

```
Unit: relative
 expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
   f1 23.86287 24.56557 23.66208 24.22205 23.91301 21.11874    10
   f2  1.00000  1.00000  1.00000  1.00000  1.00000  1.00000    10
```

which shows `f2` is `23x` faster than `f1`. If you want to boost the speed even further, you can rewrite the code in `Rcpp`.

Comment: There seems to be a speed up to be had defining `xi <- x[i]` before you enter the second loop and then use `x[j] - xi` inside the loop.

Comment: Isn't this still worst case O(n^2)?

Comment: @SimonGoater yes, still `O(n^2)`

Comment: I think your 23x times speedup claim is dubious as it will be data dependent. If the input range is say [0,1000000] and you have a million values, there will be lots of values that don't benefit from the early exit approach and the per element search will have to search to the end making it not much better than the OPs code.  Why not try to code my O(n) solution in R for a reliable performance improvement on large arrays?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know R, so I wrote this script in PHP. Hopefully, it can be read as pseudo-code by R programmers. It walks through the array and builds a look-up table of array values and their indices in the input array. It assigns a 'hilo' value of zero initially which means the hilo status has not yet been determined. If the array value + the constant value appears first in the subsequent array, the hil0 value gets set to +1 if it was not yet already determined. Likewise, it gets set to -1 if the array value - constant value appears first in the subsequent elements. I'm not sure from your description if that is exactly what you are wanting, but the general idea should carry over to whatever your output requirements are. It's somewhat similar to the famous '2 Sum' problem which often comes up in coding exercises.

As it walks through the input array it sets the hilo values of previous elements which are stored in the look-up table, which in this case is a PHP array. A slightly simpler version of the program I posted earlier suffers from performance issues when the input array has lots of duplicate values because of the linear search on the index values each time for that value, so I made an updated version which moves the determined values to a separate array. It no longer suffers from the same issue and is something like O(n) time complexity. It can solve for an input array of a million values in a few seconds.

```
<?php
// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78161294/efficient-identification-of-high-low-hits-in-a-long-vector

function printhilos($input, $determined) {
  $valuesperline = 10;
  $valuesthisline = 0;
  foreach($input as $key => $value) {
    $hilo = 0;
    if (isset($determined[$value][$key])) $hilo = $determined[$value][$key];
    echo "(".$value.",".$hilo.") ";
    $valuesthisline++;
    if ($valuesthisline >= $valuesperline) {
      echo "\n";
      $valuesthisline = 0;
    }
  }
  echo "\n";
}


function randominput($size) {
  $input = array();
  for ($i=0; $i<$size; $i++) $input[$i] = (rand() % 19998) - 9999;
  return $input;
}

  //$input = array(3, 27, 13, 37, 17, 3);
  $input = randominput($argv[1]);
  $const = 10;
  $determined = array();
  $undetermined = array();
  $indexes = array();
  foreach($input as $key => $value) {
    $undetermined[$value][$key] = 0;
    $valuehi = $value + $const;
    $valuelo = $value - $const;
    if (Array_Key_Exists($valuehi, $undetermined)) {
      $indexes = $undetermined[$valuehi];
      foreach($indexes as $index => $hilo) {
        unset($undetermined[$valuehi][$index]);
        $determined[$valuehi][$index] = -1;
      }
    }
    if (Array_Key_Exists($valuelo, $undetermined)) {
      $indexes = $undetermined[$valuelo];
      foreach($indexes as $index => $hilo) {
        unset($undetermined[$valuelo][$index]);
        $determined[$valuelo][$index] = 1;
      }
    }
  }
  printhilos($input, $determined);

?>
```

Example output with constant 10 from php hiorlo1st.php 100

```
(-21,-1) (23,0) (-53,-1) (94,-1) (-84,-1) (-67,1) (12,0) (-93,1) (55,0) (84,1) 
(19,1) (29,0) (-63,1) (70,-1) (-20,-1) (-16,1) (-88,0) (53,0) (86,0) (-72,0) 
(-66,1) (86,0) (30,1) (-66,1) (-6,0) (21,1) (68,0) (-53,-1) (-72,0) (-73,1) 
(-57,0) (64,1) (-31,-1) (40,0) (94,0) (16,-1) (57,0) (-54,0) (-48,0) (-52,0) 
(-17,1) (-89,0) (-5,1) (-26,0) (-34,0) (6,0) (-7,1) (74,-1) (53,0) (27,1) 
(-52,0) (37,-1) (60,0) (-73,1) (64,1) (-32,0) (-53,-1) (-33,1) (74,0) (-48,0) 
(5,0) (46,0) (-3,1) (-56,0) (-63,0) (-23,0) (51,1) (-81,0) (-41,0) (-41,0) 
(-30,-1) (-59,1) (12,0) (-49,0) (-56,0) (-94,0) (-35,0) (71,-1) (-81,0) (1,-1) 
(29,0) (61,0) (7,0) (7,0) (57,0) (14,0) (-76,0) (3,0) (-40,0) (-63,0) 
(81,0) (95,0) (10,0) (-11,0) (-40,0) (-14,0) (27,0) (-83,0) (31,0) (-9,0)
```